# Embedding Android AlertDialog into UI rather than pop-up

Tags: android, modal-dialog, android-alertdialog

The following Android code creates a pop-up box that can only be dismissed by clicking the (negative) button it creates.

```
DialogFragment dialog = new DialogFragment() {
  @Override
  public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
    builder.setNegativeButton(getResources().getString(R.string.abort), 
      new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {}
    });
    setCancelable(false);
    return builder.create();
  }
};  
dialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(),"");
```

Can the pop-up box be embedded into the UI (such that everything else is disabled until its button is clicked)?

Answer (score 1):

> Can the pop-up box be embedded into the UI

You could show your `DialogFragment` as a regular fragment, using a `FragmentTransaction`, indicating where you want it to appear.

> (such that everything else is disabled until its button is clicked)

That part you would need to do yourself, if you are not going to show the `DialogFragment` as an actual dialog in its own window.

Comment: I could embed into the UI without constructing the `DialogFragment`, which seems better than constructing the `DialogFragment` and pushing into the UI, because -- as you've noted -- I'd need to make sure that "everything else is disabled until its button is clicked" myself, thereby loosing the advantage of the `DialogFragment` ensuring "everything else is disabled until its button is clicked".